# Error publishing Jenkins Artifact to Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, artifactory, artifact, jenkins-2

I'm having an issue publishing a zip file into Artifactory (version 4.4.2) from Jenkins (version 2.0). Both the machines are using Windows Server 2012

all I get is the below error message, has anyone come into this problem before?

```
 For pattern: Test_Upload.zip 1 artifacts were found
Deploying artifact: http://TESTPC:####/artifactory/Test_UploadFiles/Test_Upload.zip
ERROR: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:181)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.writeTo(FileEntity.java:101)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:96)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:203)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:237)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.PreemptiveHttpClient.execute(PreemptiveHttpClient.java:88)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.execute(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:199)
    at org.jfrog.build.client.ArtifactoryHttpClient.upload(ArtifactoryHttpClient.java:195)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.uploadFile(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:618)
    at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.deployArtifact(ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java:329)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:181)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:153)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer$FilesDeployerCallable.invoke(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:121)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:990)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:968)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.GenericArtifactsDeployer.deploy(GenericArtifactsDeployer.java:80)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.generic.ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator$1.tearDown(ArtifactoryGenericConfigurator.java:340)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:173)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
```

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the Artifactory log file?

Comment: Did you finally find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Artifactory REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API) to run the same publish operation that your Jenkins job is doing - you should get some better diagnostic info.

Answer (score 0):

The following curl command can verify the credentials (assuming that it's OK to  accidentally overwrite the contents of the file),

`curl -isS https://artifactory.COMPANY.TLD/artifactory/REPO/FILE -X PUT -T ~/Downloads/FILE -u 'CI_USER:CI_PASS'`

Answer (score 0):

Creating a repository on the Artifactory UI with a repository key similar to the target in deployment stage (in jenkins pipeline) worked for me

[image: artifactory deployment stage] [image]